# Getting bug while decoding morse

Tags: java, string, morse-code

I'm trying to decode a given morse into English. However, I'm getting a bug in the code I've written. Here is my code:

```
String code=".... . -.--   .--- ..- -.. ."; //Decodes to "HEY JUDE"
String[] letters = code.split(" ");
StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
for(String str : letters){
    if(!str.equals(""))
        res.append(MorseCode.get(str));
    else res.append(" ");
}
System.out.println(res);
```

At line 7 if I write:

```
res.append(" ");
```

The output is:

> HEY   JUDE

If I write:

```
res.append("");
```

The output is:

> HEYJUDE

Comment: Your question is not clear. What problem are you facing?

Comment: And this is not a full example of the code that has whatever the issue is

Comment: I don't know how splitting works in Java. But, probably having three spaces after each other in your input `code` gives you problems.

Comment: Try use a debugger, it helps

Comment: @DavidWalschots this is likely how the messages' spaces are encoded.

Comment: What exactly is the *bug* you are talking about? Is it the three spaces between HEY and JUDE? Have you tried making just 2 spaces of it?

Comment: If I give a space the output is showing with 2 spaces. If I give no space the output is showing with no space.That's the problem

Answer (score 2):

Three consecutive spaces split around space will give you two empty strings (the empty string between the first and second consecutive spaces plus the one between the second and third consecutive spaces).

You either need to change the way the messages' spaces are encoded, or handle these two consecutive empty strings. Assuming you can't change the messages' encoding and that spaces always comes alone (letter separator) or by three (encoded space), the following would work :

```
String code=".... . -.--   .--- ..- -.. ."; //Decodes to "HEY JUDE"
Iterator<String> letters = Arrays.asList(code.split(" ")).iterator();
StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
while(letters.hasNext()) {
    String current = letters.next();
    if (! "".equals(current)) { // we have a letter
        res.append(MorseCode.get(current));
    } else { // we have an empty string, the first of two which represent a space
        res.append(" ");
        letters.next(); // we skip the next item which will be an empty string
    }
}
System.out.println(res);
```

You can [try it here](https://ideone.com/jea14k) (with the letter represented as `x` since I don't have your MorseCode class).

Comment: Perhaps a regex expression to handle two or more consecutive space characters being translated to a single `\\s` character would be a good solution to the problem.

Comment: @Bryan which problem are you talking about? I'm not sure how your comment relates to my answer, which I believe is a good solution to OP's problem.

Comment: My apologies. Your solution is solid, I was vague in my response. I was referring to the first sentence of the second paragraph of your answer about suggesting to the OP how to handle the encoding of the empty characters.

Comment: @Bryan I believe OP's morse code represents the spaces in the original message as three consecutive spaces ; if he replaced the 2+ consecutive spaces by a single space he'd lost the spaces and just output `HEYJUDE`. However I think spaces are usually encoded as slashes in morse code, so replacing three consecutive spaces by `  /  ` might be much easier than my solution if his MorseCode handles slashes.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why you are trying to solve this with only one loop. Simpler and probably more readable solution would be

1. splitting `code` on 3 spaces to get all individual encoded "words" like `".... . -.--"` and `".--- ..- -.. ."`
2. split each encoded "word" on 1 space to get single Morse code sequence `".... . -.--"` -> `"...."` `"."` `"-.--"`

Then you can

- convert Morse code to letter,
- join decoded letters into words,
- join words into sentence (separate them with space).

So your code can look like

```
StringJoiner sentence = new StringJoiner(" ");    // decoded words should be 
                                                  // separated with single space
for (String section : code.split("   ")){ 
    StringBuilder word = new StringBuilder();
    for(String morse : section.split(" ")){
        word.append(MorseCode.get(morse));
    }
    sentence.add(word.toString());
}

String result = sentence.toString();
```

If you don't like recreating StringBuilder in each iteration (for each word) you can create one before loop and reset it at start of each iteration with `setLength(0)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a `Map<String, String>` as dictionary, you could do something like this. Replace `null` values with `' '` and keep track of the `char` printed before in the loop in order to print only one space character.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class MorseCode {

    static Map<String, Character> morseDictionary;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        morseDictionary = new HashMap<String, Character>();
        morseDictionary.put("....", 'H');
        morseDictionary.put(".", 'E');
        morseDictionary.put("-.--", 'Y');
        morseDictionary.put(".---", 'J');
        morseDictionary.put("..-", 'U');
        morseDictionary.put("-..", 'D');

        String morseCode = ".... . -.--   .--- ..- -.. .";
        printTranslationOf(morseCode);
    }

    public static void printTranslationOf(String morseCode) {

        String[] singleCharacters = morseCode.split(" ");

        List<Character> latinCharacters = new ArrayList<Character>();

        char lastChar = ' ';
        for (String character : singleCharacters) {
            char printable = morseDictionary.get(character) == null ?
                    ' ' : morseDictionary.get(character);

            if (printable == ' ') {
                if (lastChar != ' ') {
                    latinCharacters.add(printable);
                }
            } else {
                latinCharacters.add(printable);
            }

            lastChar = printable;
        }

        latinCharacters.forEach((Character character) -> {
            System.out.print(character);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This still has the problem OP is trying to fix ([outputs `HEY  JUDE` instead of `HEY JUDE`](https://ideone.com/wG0cDR))

Comment: @Aaron It has, indeed... I will fix that later, can't do it on mobile device at the moment.

Comment: @Aaron edited the answer, should work now. But the one given by Pshemo is much better.